# Пройтись циклом по асинхронному замыканию Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

Как пройтись циклом по замыканию(Alamofile).
У меня происходит зацикливание, поскольку не меняется переменная вне цикла.
Пример:

```
func getRegion2(){
    let method = "region/"
    var url = serviceUrl+method
    var i = 0
    while(i < 4){

        Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in

            i = i + 1
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):

                let nextUrl = JSON(data)["next"].stringValue
                url = nextUrl

                print(i)
                print(nextUrl)

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример выше - упрощенный пример. Суть в том, что в результате выполнения исходного запроса будет получен массив данных и, возможно, ссылка на следующую часть массива, которую нужно догрузить. До тех пор пока nextUrl не станет пустым нужно дополнять массив.
Если я правильно понимаю, тут нужно управлять потоком, но как именно это сделать не могу понять.

Пример как задумывается:

```
func getRegion2(){
let method = "region/"
val myArray = [String]()
var url = serviceUrl+method
while(url != nil){

    Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):

            let nextUrl = JSON(data)["next"].stringValue
            url = nextUrl

            //Тут заполняем массив данных myArray


            print(nextUrl)

        case .failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Решение данной проблемы - рекурсия.
Пару примеров решения: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260037/async-task-dont-change-external-variable-swift-3/40266138#40266138

Answer (score 1):

Вы сами написали, что замыкание асинхронное - значит оно будет выполнено не в момент исполнения, а лишь по определённому событию, плюс - вероятнее всего выполнение блока будет так же происходить в главном потоке, а значит - не произойдёт никогда, потому что поток будет полностью занят зависшим циклом. Если вам надо модифицировать какую-то переменную в аисинхронном блоке - лучше делать это в synchronize, но в вашем случае это не ответ. Хотелось бы понять, какая именно цель вашей переменной? Если нужно передать значение i в блок, то стоит, например попробовать найти у Alamofire-запроса что-нибудь типа userData и записывать переменную в него и в блоке оттуда же и доставать. Другой вариант - использовать промежуточную константу, например так:

```
func getRegion2(){
    let method = "region/"
    var url = serviceUrl+method
    var i = 0
    while(i < 4){
        i = i + 1
        let iBlock = i
        Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):

                let nextUrl = JSON(data)["next"].stringValue
                url = nextUrl

                print(iBlock)
                print(nextUrl)

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, к сожалению. Дело в том, что в результате загрузки файла я получу nextUrl, а также массив. Так вот, если nextUrl не пустой, то нужно снова запросить(дозагрузить) данные.

Comment: Сделайте отдельный метод запроса, который просто будет принимать url и i. Ну и если нужно перезапросить - опять же вызываешь метод с тем же i, но уже с nextUrl.

Comment: Пробовал. Всё равно зацикливается. Мне кажется, что нужно как то притормозить поток, но как непонятно. Я понимаю, что это решается синхронными вызовами, но раз уж столкнулся с проблемой нужно попробовать её решить.

Comment: Зацикливалось потому что было `i = i + 1` внутри блока, я же в своём примере вынес его выше, тут зацикливания в принципе не может произойти

Comment: Логика в том, что данные изменяются именно внутри блока.

Comment: Логика в том, что ты твой код её лишён. While у тебя проходит по переменной локального стека, которая никогда не изменяется, вайл вечно будет ходить по i=0. Как бы ты не изменял какую-либо переменную - она не должна быть итератором цикла. А твой код сейчас делает вот что - он запускает несколько тысяч запросов в секунду до тех пор пока 4 из них не обновят переменную i и она не остановит цикл запуска запросов. А это вероятно никогда не произойдёт, потому, что эти блоки не получат управление главным потоком.

Comment: Задача в том, чтобы изменить переменную url внутри блока и если в ней есть данные, то повторно запустить этот же метод, но с других входным url. Так сделано потому что API данные загружаются по 10 элементов, а всего их около 40, значит чтобы получить массив из 40 нужно в один исходных массив сложить результат 4 последовательных вызовов. К Примеру: вызываю первый раз - сохранил массив из 10 строк, проверил nextUrl, если не пустая, значит данные нужно еще догружать по новой ссылке и т.д.

Comment: Тогда делай метод callUrl с параметрами url и result, где result - это массив, в который запросы накидывают данные. А в случае, если nextUrl получилось пустым result передаётся на обработку. Если же nextUrl пришёл - дёргаем тот же метод, с новым nextUrl и старым result